# MySQL comparing two BLOB or TEXT data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, blob

I have two 20k plates data for each company in my PHP application. I store them in string arrays. And I'm planning to serialize each of them and save as TEXT inside MySQL cell.

```
--company_id----|--plates1---------|--plates2--------
------------------------------------------------------
---------1------|--(TEXT $data1a)--|--(TEXT $data1b)--
---------2------|--(TEXT $data2a)--|--(TEXT $data1b)--
```

In normal conditions I get `$data1a` and `$data1b` from database, unserialize them and compare their elements and find the common ones different ones. It becomes time and memory-consuming to compare them like this.

(Saving each element of  `$data1a` as a row is not an option, because there exists 30k companies and each of them has that much of plates)

Is there a way to save TEXT data to MySQL table in a special way and get the compared values after a query. Or TEXT is strictly a block that can't be broken into parts?

Comment: Why is breaking the array into relational data for insertion into a relational database "not an option"?  With suitable indexing and partitioning, MySQL can cope with tables of order 30k^2.

Comment: if you are gonna save alot of data, use blob because i do believe Text has a char limit, even tho its pretty high, but as @eggyal said way not just create tables for that kind of data.

Comment: You are violating the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity) and therefore the 1NF, and suffering the consequences of that. B-Trees scale logarithmically with the number of rows, so @eggyal is right - that many rows should not be a problem at all in a well designed and indexed database.